# program not returning proper results and compilation error

Tags: java, compilation, output

This code is going to be the end of me.... it runs fine now (kinda) but not getting the proper results.... when inputting 7267881 from the sample file it says it is invalid however for others in the file 
it gives the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The import src cannot be resolved

    at Account.<init>(Account.java:1)
    at AcccountArray.main(AcccountArray.java:45)
```

Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class AcccountArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Scan the file and save account details to array
        File file = new File ("customers.txt");
        System.out.println("Path : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("customers.txt"));
            String[][] Account = new String[Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine())][3];

                    for(int i=0;i<Account.length;i++)
                    {
                        Account[i][0]=scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(Account[i][0]);
                        Account[i][1]=scanner.nextLine();
                        Account[i][2]=scanner.nextLine();
                        //System.out.println(Account[i][2]);
                    }
                    scanner.close();

                Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter account number: ");
                String accountNumber = userinput.next();
                int matchindex = 0;
                Boolean match = false;

                for (int k =0;k<Account.length;k++)
                {
                    if(Account[k][1].equals(accountNumber))
                    {
                        match = true;
                        matchindex = k;
                    }
                }

                if(match)
                {
                    Account ac =  new Account();
                    ac.toString(Account[matchindex][0], Account[matchindex][1], Account[matchindex][2]);
                    System.out.println("Enter 'D' for deposite\nEnter 'W' for withdrawal\nEnter 'Q' for quit");

                    Scanner transaction = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String type = transaction.next();

                    Scanner ammount = new Scanner(System.in);
                    switch (type) {
                    case "D":
                        System.out.println("Enter the ammount : ");
                        float diposit = ammount.nextFloat();
                        float curent = Float.valueOf(Account[matchindex][2]);
                        System.out.println("New balance = "+(curent+diposit));
                        break;
                    case "W":
                        System.out.println("Enter the ammount : ");
                        float withdrawal = ammount.nextFloat();
                        float balance = Float.valueOf(Account[matchindex][2]);
                        System.out.println("New balance = "+(balance-withdrawal));
                        break;
                    case "Q":
                        System.out.println("Exit");
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid transaction");

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid user account number");
                }


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}





import src.String;

public class Account 
{

public String toString(String name,String account,String balance)
{
    System.out.println("Customer name :\t\t "+name);
    System.out.println("Account Number :\t "+ account);
    System.out.println("Current Balance :\t $"+ balance);
    return null;
}

}
```

test file

```
4
John Anderson
4565413
250.00
Louise Carter 
2323472
1250.45 
Paul Johnson
7267881 
942.81
Sarah Wilson  
0982377
311.26
```

Comment: Hard to help you if you don't tell us what the proper results should look like.

Comment: Using an identifier that is *identical* to a class name, might be a little misleading for outsiders looking at your code. `Account`?

Comment: @BobbyDigital Right, and btw, the Account class is totally useless. Though it seems instead of a String[][] he should use Account[].

Comment: You need to create a valid Account class and test it before working with a large main method. You need to make sure your code *compiles* before you run it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `import src.String;` before the `Account` class.

- If you need to use the `java.lang.String` class, you can use it without an `import` statement
- But if you have defined your own `String` class, you will not be able to import it until you remove it from the default package. When you move the class to another package, the `import com.mypackage.String` statement **must** be on top of the `AccountArray` class.

Comment: @user2954611: you mean you still have the **same** error message if you get rid of this erroneous import?

Comment: oh I lied it solved one of them, but not the error with the one number that is not detected

Comment: 7267881 is still not recognized

Comment: @user2954611: You shouldn't try to run uncompilable code. Fix the compilation errors first.

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you do not have a compilation problem! 
Before running the program, correct all compilation errors.

Only then makes it sense to look for strange behaviour of your program.